# Where is the Micro:Bit TypeScript randint() Function Documented?

Tags: javascript, typescript, bbc-microbit

I am trying* to teach a class of high school students to transition from block coding to JavaScript (really Static TypeScript) on the Micro:Bit.

The `pickrandom` block translates into a call to `randint()`  I would have expected a call to `Math.randint(`) but apparently `randint()` is a global function in TypeScript.

The first question the kids are going to ask is "Where can I find out about other global functions?" and, after almost two hours with Google, I can't find the answer to that question.

So, where is `randint()` documented and where is a list of other such functions?

* Context: I'm a retired college teacher who "became volunteered" to help out during the pandemic.

Comment: It seems to be declared [here](https://github.com/microsoft/pxt/blob/23444e0465783d0acede1ac0dcdbb9e20adab001/libs/pxt-common/pxt-core.d.ts#L390-L400)

Comment: @Bergi Thank you.  That certainly helped me.  I'm still looking for a reference that's friendlier to beginning students.

Comment: I think it is defined somewhere in the respective [compiler backend](https://github.com/microsoft/pxt/blob/master/docs/language.md). I couldn't locate the source code anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be worth having a read of the [documentation from Lancaster University](https://lancaster-university.github.io/microbit-docs/concepts/#concepts). Squeezing the high level languages into something that runs on a tiny micro-controller means connecting into the Device Abstraction Layer (DAL) and so things like the randint are micro:bit specific.

As a result, for the different languages they look very similar:

- https://lancaster-university.github.io/microbit-docs/ubit/#int-random-int-max
- https://makecode.microbit.org/reference/math/randint
- https://microbit-micropython.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0.1/random.html?highlight=randint#random.randint

Comment: How did you find the second link in your list?  I can't find a path from "reference" to "randint."

Comment: I am assuming you are using the JavaScript editor inside of Makecode. I right click on the randint keyword in the code and then select help. You can then click on the icon to pop out the help page.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really a JavaScript / Typescript issue. There is no randint() function in these languages. It is micro:bit specific. To see all available commands see the documentation at https://makecode.microbit.org/reference

Comment: Thanks.  I've edited the question to be "Where is randint() defined" rather than "Where in TypeScript...?"  The reference in your link is to blocks.  I'm looking for a reference that shows the randint() function as used in TypeScript for Micro:Bit.

Comment: https://makecode.microbit.org/reference/math/randint